# Converting unsigned char * to hexstring

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, stringstream

Below code takes a hex string(every byte is represented as its corresponidng hex value)
converts it to unsigned char * buffer and then converts back to hex string.
This code is testing the conversion from unsigned char* buffer to hex string
which I need to send over the network to a receiver process.
I chose hex string as unsigned char can be in range of 0 to 255 and there is no printable character after 127.
The below code just tells the portion that bugs me. Its in the comment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
// converts a hexstring to corresponding integer. i.e "c0" - > 192
int convertHexStringToInt(const string & hexString)
{
  stringstream geek;
  int x=0;

  geek << std::hex << hexString;
  geek >> x;

  return x;
}

// converts a complete hexstring to unsigned char * buffer
void convertHexStringToUnsignedCharBuffer(string hexString, unsigned char* 
hexBuffer)
{
  int i=0;
  while(hexString.length())
  {
    string hexStringPart = hexString.substr(0,2);
    hexString = hexString.substr(2);
    int hexStringOneByte = convertHexStringToInt (hexStringPart);
    hexBuffer[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>((hexStringOneByte & 0xFF)) ;
    i++;
  }
}

int main()
{
  //below hex string is a hex representation of a unsigned char * buffer.
  //this is generated by an excryption algorithm in unsigned char* format
  //I am converting it to hex string to make it printable for verification pupose.
  //and takes the hexstring as inpuit here to test the conversion logic.
  string inputHexString = "552027e33844dd7b71676b963c0b8e20";
  string outputHexString;
  stringstream geek;

  unsigned char * hexBuffer = new unsigned char[inputHexString.length()/2];
  convertHexStringToUnsignedCharBuffer(inputHexString, hexBuffer);

  for (int i=0;i<inputHexString.length()/2;i++)
  {
    geek <<std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')<<(0xFF&hexBuffer[i]); // this works
    //geek <<std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')<<(hexBuffer[i]); -- > this does not work
    // I am not able to figure out why I need to do the bit wise and operation with unsigned char "0xFF&hexBuffer[i]"
    // without this the conversion does not work for individual bytes having ascii values more than 127.
  }

  geek >> outputHexString;

  cout << "input hex string:  " << inputHexString<<endl;
  cout << "output hex string: " << outputHexString<<endl;
  if(0 == inputHexString.compare(outputHexString))
    cout<<"hex encoding successful"<<endl;
  else
    cout<<"hex encoding failed"<<endl;

  if(NULL != hexBuffer)
      delete[] hexBuffer;

  return 0;
}

// output
// can some one explain ? I am sure its something silly that I am missing.
```

Comment: `unsigned char * hexBuffer = new unsigned char(inputHexString.length()/2);` allocates 1 byte which you go on to overflow. Maybe you meant to use square brackets. Also you never delete it. All of these problems could be avoided by using `std::vector`

Comment: You are right. I meant to use square bracket and I should delete it. This was rather a quickly drafted code to explain my confusion about the solution. I completely missed those bugs as the output was what I desired. I understand it would be best to fix those bugs and put a cleaner code. Thanks for pointing those out !
std::vector would be a better solution but I need to work with unsigned char * buffer as it is what I get as data type for the tag type from AES_GCM mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of an `unsigned char` is like the output of a `char` which obviously does not what the OP expects.

I tested the following on coliru:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Output of (unsigned char)0xc0: "
    << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned char)0xc0 << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

and got:

```
Output of (unsigned char)0xc0: 0�
```

This is caused by the `std::ostream::operator<<()` which is chosen out of the available operators. I looked on cppreference

- [**operator<<(std::basic_ostream)**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) and
- [**std::basic_ostream::operator<<**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)

and found

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        unsigned char ch );
```

in the former (with a little bit help from M.M).

The OP suggested a fix: bit-wise And with `0xff` which seemed to work. Checking this in coliru.com:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Output of (unsigned char)0xc0: "
    << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (0xff & (unsigned char)0xc0) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Output of (unsigned char)0xc0: c0
```

Really, this seems to work. Why?

`0xff` is an `int` constant (stricly speaking: an [**integer literal**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)) and has type `int`. Hence, the bit-wise And promotes `(unsigned char)0xc0` to `int` as well, yields the result of type `int`, and hence, the `std::ostream::operator<<` for `int` is applied.

This is an option to solve this. I can provide another one – just converting the `unsigned char` to `unsigned`.

Where the promotion of `unsigned char` to `int` introduces a possible sign-bit extension (which is undesired in this case), this doesn't happen when `unsigned char` is converted to `unsigned`. The output stream operator for `unsigned` provides the intended output as well:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Output of (unsigned char)0xc0: "
    << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned)(unsigned char)0xc0 << '\n';
  const unsigned char c = 0xc0;
  std::cout << "Output of unsigned char c = 0xc0: "
    << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned)c << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Output of (unsigned char)0xc0: c0
Output of unsigned char c = 0xc0: c0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5672e8bf3bcdc089)

Comment: @Scheff Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: @M.M Yepp - fixed it again.

Comment: @M.M It was the fifth in the other link `operator<<(std::basic_ostream)`, and I've to admit a case of temporary blindness that I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

the C++20 way:

```
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[]{ "Hello world\n\t\r\0" };
std::size_t data_size = sizeof("Hello world\n\t\r\0") - 1;

auto sp = std::span(data, data_size );
std::transform( sp.begin(), sp.end(),
                std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout),
                [](unsigned char c) -> std::string {
                    return std::format("{:02X}", int(c));
                });
```

or if you want to store result into string:

```
std::string result{};
result.reserve(size * 2 + 1);
std::transform( sp.begin(), sp.end(),
                std::back_inserter(result),
                [](unsigned char c) -> std::string {
                    return std::format("{:02X}", int(c));
                });
```

```
Output:
48656C6C6F20776F726C640A090D00
```